# Is there an upper bound on the number of partitions of a finite set of primes into 3 sets the products of 2 of which sum to the product of the third?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

Is there an upper bound on the number of partitions of a finite set $S$
of prime numbers into 3 sets $A$, $B$ and $C$ for which the following holds?:
$$
  \prod_{p \in A} p \ + \ \prod_{p \in B} p \ = \ \prod_{p \in C} p
$$
And if yes: which is the maximum possible number of such partitions,
and for which set(s) does it occur?

If an answer to this is out of reach: what can be said under the
assumption of reasonable conjectures, or at least what is to be
expected heuristically?

*Examples:* Put $S := \{2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 17, 23\}$. Then we have
\begin{align*}
  S =& \ \{5, 17\} \cup \{3, 23\} \cup \{2, 7, 11\} \\
    =& \ \{7, 17\} \cup \{2, 23\} \cup \{3, 5, 11\} \\
    =& \ \{11, 17\} \cup \{23\} \cup \{2, 3, 5, 7\} \\
    =& \ \{2, 5, 11\} \cup \{3, 17\} \cup \{7, 23\} \\
    =& \ \{5, 7, 11\} \cup \{2, 3\} \cup \{17, 23\} \\
    =& \ \{2, 7, 17\} \cup \{3, 5\} \cup \{11, 23\},
\end{align*}
corresponding to
\begin{align*}
  5 \cdot 17 + 3 \cdot 23 &= 2 \cdot 7 \cdot 11, \\
  7 \cdot 17 + 2 \cdot 23 &= 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 11, \\
  11 \cdot 17 + 23 &= 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7, \\
  2 \cdot 5 \cdot 11 + 3 \cdot 17 &= 7 \cdot 23, \\
  5 \cdot 7 \cdot 11 + 2 \cdot 3 &= 17 \cdot 23, \\
  2 \cdot 7 \cdot 17 + 3 \cdot 5 &= 11 \cdot 23.
\end{align*}
Similarly, put
$S := \{2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 29, 41, 47, 59\}$. Then we have
\begin{align*}
  S =& \ \{2, 3, 5, 13, 17, 59\} \cup \{11\} \cup \{7, 29, 41, 47\} \\
    =& \ \{2, 3, 5, 17, 47\} \cup \{7, 13, 29\} \cup \{11, 41, 59\} \\
    =& \ \{2, 5, 7, 17, 47\} \cup \{13, 41\} \cup \{3, 11, 29, 59\} \\
    =& \ \{3, 7, 41, 47\} \cup \{17, 59\} \cup \{2, 5, 11, 13, 29\} \\
    =& \ \{3, 11, 13, 29\} \cup \{2, 5, 17, 41\} \cup \{7, 47, 59\} \\
    =& \ \{3, 13, 29, 41\} \cup \{2, 5, 7, 11\} \cup \{17, 47, 59\} \\
    =& \ \{7, 29, 59\} \cup \{3, 11, 13, 17\} \cup \{2, 5, 41, 47\} \\
    =& \ \{13, 17, 47\} \cup \{5, 29, 59\} \cup \{2, 3, 7, 11, 41\} \\
\end{align*}
corresponding to
\begin{align*}
  2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 13 \cdot 17 \cdot 59 + 11 &= 7 \cdot 29 \cdot 41 \cdot 47, \\
  2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 17 \cdot 47 + 7 \cdot 13 \cdot 29 &= 11 \cdot 41 \cdot 59, \\
  2 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 17 \cdot 47 + 13 \cdot 41 &= 3 \cdot 11 \cdot 29 \cdot 59, \\
  3 \cdot 7 \cdot 41 \cdot 47 + 17 \cdot 59 &= 2 \cdot 5 \cdot 11 \cdot 13 \cdot 29, \\
  3 \cdot 11 \cdot 13 \cdot 29 + 2 \cdot 5 \cdot 17 \cdot 41 &= 7 \cdot 47 \cdot 59, \\
  3 \cdot 13 \cdot 29 \cdot 41 + 2 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 11 &= 17 \cdot 47 \cdot 59, \\
  7 \cdot 29 \cdot 59 + 3 \cdot 11 \cdot 13 \cdot 17 &= 2 \cdot 5 \cdot 41 \cdot 47, \\
  13 \cdot 17 \cdot 47 + 5 \cdot 29 \cdot 59 &= 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 7 \cdot 11 \cdot 41.
\end{align*}
Among the $2^{17} = 131072$ sets of prime numbers less than 60, eight
distinct such partitions is the maximum, and happens exactly for the set
given above. Besides, 3 of the sets admit 6 such partitions, 16 sets admit
5 such partitions, 57 sets admit 4 such partitions, 276 sets admit
3 such partitions, 1498 sets admit 2 such partitions, 7708 sets admit
one such parrtition, and 121513 sets admit no such partition (among the
latter are obviously all $2^{16} = 65536$ such sets which do not contain 2).